# Iframe content URL disappear after 3 second

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to dynamically change the iframe URL, for doing so I'm calling to the `window.onmessage = (event) =>` function and fire the URL as `event.data` variable, this happened from external button.

When I click on the external button the iframe is shown the right URL but after 3 seconds change to black (blank URL), why does it happen, and how to solve it?

**

- The ifame code

**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/pinned-octocat.svg" color="#000000">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
      
    <style> 
        body { background: #232323; width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; }
        
        /* Responsive Container for iFrame */
        .embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } 
        .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    
    <title>Tech Ops PH | your &lt; IT / design &lt; partner </title>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">


   
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
      
     document.getElementById("myIframe").src=event.data

      
    }
  
 }

</script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class='embed-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3'>
  <iframe id="myIframe"  width="600" height="9000"  frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is button? Can you show me the source of the button attached to the question?

Comment: Sure, 
`export function button5_click(event) {
 $w("#myHtmlComponent").postMessage("https://www.thesun.co.uk/") 
 
 
}`